# Will this query work as expected?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql table with only one column, the column has got some 3 letter words and some 4 letter words, and some 5 and 6 letter words.

I want a query to at first select randomly from all 3 letter words, when they're all gone, then move on to 4 letter words, and so on.

This is my query:

```
SELECT `word` FROM `words` ORDER BY LENGTH(`word`) ASC, RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This works as expected so far in the few times I've tried, but I'd like to be sure that it'll always work like this.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me, but I hope the table is small because MySQL will be scanning all the rows every time and then using filesort, all to return a single row.

Comment: @Ami It will have about 4k-5k records. Will it be more efficient to add another column with the length of the words, then do `ORDER by wordLength ASC, RAND()`?

Comment: @Click Upvote yes, before reading your comment question, I was getting ready to tell you the exact same thing. Please explain what "when they're all gone means". Are you deleting rows after they get returned?

Comment: No, unfortunately, that would not help, since the RAND() would still require a full table scan and filesort. Look for my extended answer below, coming soon...

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan Yes, I am, but they will be deleted as users demand, not all in one sitting

Comment: @Ami RAND() will not require a full table scan. MySQL will first order by the length column, then it will randomly and directly return one row based on the index of the `length` column (assuming there is an index).

Comment: @ClickUpvote, is there more than one user selecting random words? Does it have to be random for multiple users? In other words, can the order be repeated for the same words?

Comment: @Ami Yes, more than one users can be selecting, no, it can't be repeated

Comment: @ClickUpvote, darn then I don't have any better answer than below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks fine to me, but I hope the table is small because MySQL will be scanning all the rows every time and then using filesort, all to return a single row.

Adding a `wordlength` column and indexing it will not improve the query because the `ORDER BY RAND()` function would invalidate use of the index.

Consider splitting the words up into separate tables, depending on their length, at least you'll only be scanning all rows for words of the same length. Select from the three_letter_words table first, and if there are no results, then select from the four_letter_words table, and so on.

Comment: What if I did `Select.. WHERE wordLength = 3 ORDER BY RAND()` and when 3 letter words run out, then `WHERE wordLength = 4` and so on?

Comment: @ClickUpvote, Ah, yes! I was just thinking the same thing. That's easier (in code) than managing multiple tables, but at the cost of keeping an index up to date. I think it's a good compromise, don't want to overoptimize and make it hard on yourself. If you're using InnoDB, use an auto-incrementing primary key for fast inserts.

Comment: Why would using a primary key make the inserts faster?

Comment: @ClickUpvote, forget what I said, come back for optimization later. :)